# Input date ta em inglês

Tags: jquery, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Fiz um input date do bootstrap e ele ta em inglês, há alguma forma dele ficar em pt-br?

HTML

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<div class="container">
        <div class='col-md-5'>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-5'>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

JQUERY

```
  $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
  });
```

Comment: pode colocar os imports da biblioteca que esta utilizando?

Comment: @JulioHenrique acabei de colocar

Answer (score 1):

No seu exemplo vc esta usando a versao em frances `bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js`

pt-br entao vc precisa mudar esse link para:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente colocar o trecho

```
locale: 'pt-br'
```

após o `useCurrent: false`

ps: coloque uma vírgula após o 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode tentar assim

Tente colocar no início da página logo abaixo do `<!DOCTYPE html>` a qual idioma a página se refere, tipo: `<html lang="pt-br">`

Depois tente coloque esse script apos todos os outros CDNs de `<script>`

```
<script>
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    });
</script>
```

Dessa forma ele pega a data no formato desejado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class='col-xs-4 input-group date'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div><br>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ele ainda continua ingles :T

Comment: Maria nesse caso sugiro vc testar seu código em outro .html apenas com o Datapicker para tentar descobrir aonde está o conflito, pois no Snippet que eu posteu vc pode ver que a data está em "português" Ou então use o meu exemplo e vai colocando o restante do seu código na página até descobrir o que está alterando o formato da data.

Comment: Mas eu quero ele em portugues, e no snippet do seu exemplo ainda ta em inglês...os meses e semanas

Comment: Então o seu problema é com o seu Sistema Operacional ou com a Versão do seu Browser. Se eles estiverem em inglês provavelmente o input deve seguir a linguagem default